# How do I connect a creditcard to my website?

Tags: php, paypal, payment

I wonder how I connect a credit card to my website? The payment should be like an Apple-ID account where it draws money directly from the credit card without some furthermore inputs of the user(though the user needs to accept this payment method at the first time). I have trouble finding it in PayPals document. Do you have an answer I would preferrably have it in PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a credit card processor like paypal, esellerate or kagi.  The implementation for transaction processing differs based on the company that is doing the transaction.  You must implement the APIs they provide, and they do the real world processing on your behalf.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend this page: http://www.e-junkie.com/ej/paypal-for-digital-goods.htm
That is even linked to on Paypal.com's main page.

Otherwise, they have the 'easy' method, which uses 'Buy Now' style buttons. However, the 'standard' plan does SEND the user to Paypal for processing. More information on that at: https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant/wp_standard

You don't need PHP if you use the standard route, you can just use HTML buttons. Configuration options are located at: https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables

You can also use [this link](https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ButtonMgrAPIIntro) to have it generate the html code for you.

Best of luck, Paypal is easy if you are willing to let them leave your site for purchases. Otherwise, you'll need the 'pro' plan, which I believe does cost a monthly fee to use, but the user can stay on your site.